# Get out of a folder using Git Bash

Tags: windows, git, github, git-bash

I am using Git Bash and am trying a few things like making a 'commit' and 'push' to GitHub. 
I want to get out of the current directory `C:\user\myUsername\app` and land in the `C:\user\myUsername` folder.

What commands do I write in Git Bash?

Comment: use `cd ..` its a windows prompt command.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Note: `cd..` works only in windows command prompt, whereas `cd ..` works almost everywhere - including (linux) bash and (my) Git bash.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

To change your directory in git-bash to that specific path you can use this command :

```
cd /c/user/myUsername
```

basically you have to replace backslash with standard slash, or otherwise if you simply want to go to the parent directory you can use :

```
cd ..
```

as stated in comments that you already received on your question ...

Comment: It's interesting that the drives in Windows are top-level (bottom-level?) directories in the Bash shell.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and in Git Bash, the command "cd .." does not work. It does not move me one directory upwards. Space or no space.

Answer (score 42):

Just wanted to add, make sure to insert space between cd and ..

```
no: cd..
yes: cd ..
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to move one directory up, just type command `cd ..` if you are following any tutorials most probably they will use macOS so that means they will use there own linux commands like

> `cd/home/your username`.So just click type `cd ..` it will leads to go to previous directory.Most probably people will type like this `cd ..users/username` so don't do that mistake; just type `cd ..` .

Other mistakes:
don't type :- `cd..`
do :- `cd ..`

give space between cd and dots.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quickly move one directory up in git bash, type the command cd ../ and make sure there is a SPACE between cd and .. My version of Gitbash will NOT do anything if I type cd .. ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this command in git-bash to go back to the previous directory :

```
 cd -
```

The above command does the same as `cd ..`